# ImageView causing App to crash

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a singleview application in Android Studio with one TextView. When I try to add an ImageView, the application crashes after building (Zero Gradle errors). When I remove the ImageView the application works perfectly on the emulator.

Here's the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.agileworks.agileworks.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What are the crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I removed the image from the drawable folder and used a different image file, which fixed the issue. Guess I should have started with that!